# How can I see if an element in an int array is empty?

Tags: java, arrays

example:

I want to see if `array[5]` holds a value or is empty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Elements in primitive arrays can't be empty.  They'll always get initialized to something (usually `0` for `int` arrays, but depends on how you declare the array).

If you declare the array like so (for example):

```
int [] myArray ;
myArray = new int[7] ;
```

then all of the elements will default to `0`.

An alternative syntax for declaring arrays is

```
int[] myArray = { 12, 7, 32, 15, 113, 0, 7 };
```

where the initial values for an array (of size seven in this case) are given in the curly braces `{}`.

Comment: Just as an aside, I believe (though I am not 100% on this) that int[] myArray = new int[] {12, 7, 32, 15, 113, 0, 7}; is also allowed.  That is, I believe you are allowed (though you do not have to) to put new int[] in front of your created array.

Comment: @MetroidFan2002:  Yes, that syntax is also valid.

Comment: If you want Null values, you should declare it as Integer [] array.  The problem with using int[] is that you can't tell the difference between someone assigning a 0 value, and it having defaulted to that.  If this is OK, then you can use the primitive.  If you need to know the difference, you'll have to use Integer.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as an "empty" element in a Java array. If the array's length is at least six, then element 5 exists and it has a value. If you have not assigned anything else to that location, then it will have the value zero, just like an object's uninitialized field would have.

If it is an array of `Object` descendants, then you can check whether the element is equal to `null`.

Comment: what is stored in element 5 if nothing has been assigned to it then?

Comment: Integers are initialized to 0 by default.

Comment: it's dependent on the array's component type.  for all numerical primitives, it's 0.  For char it's ascii code 0 (aka the null char).  For byte, it's byte value 0.  For boolean it would be false.  And for any non-primitive (ie an Object), it's null.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define what you mean by empty. Depending on the datatype of the array you can decide on the semantics of empty. For example, if you have an array of ints you can decide that 0 is empty. Or if the array is of reference types then you can decide that null is empty. Then you simply check by comparing array[5] == null or array[5] == 0 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive arrays (int, float, char, etc) are never "empty" (by which I assume you mean "null"), because primitive array elements can never be null.

By default, an int array usually contains 0 when allocated.  However, I never rely on this (spent too much time writing C code, I guess).

One way is to pick a value that you want to treat as "uninitialized".  It could be 0, or -1, or some other value that you're not going to use as a valid value.  Initialize your array to that value after allocating it.

Object arrays (String[] and any array of objects that extend Object), *can* have null elements, so you could create an Integer[] array and initialize it to nulls. I think I like that idea better than using a magic value as described above.

Comment: int will always default to 0, this is defined in the Java language specification

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use objects rather than primitives.

```
Integer[] myArray …
… Objects.isNull( myArray[ 5 ] ) …
… Objects.nonNull( myArray[ 5 ] ) …
```

## Use objects, not primitives ➠ <s>`int[]`</s> `Integer[]`

The [Answer by Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/286167/642706) is correct. An **array of primitive values has no empty** slots. All slots hold an element with a default value for that data type. For `int`, the default is `0`, zero.

If you want to track empty slots, or “holes”, in your array, define the array as **holding object references rather than primitive** values. So you would want a `Integer[]` rather than <s>`int[]`</s>.

```
Integer[] integers = new Integer[ 12 ] ;
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( integers ) ) ;
```

### `null`

When run we see that all the elements are `null`. This means no object references has yet been placed in that slot.

> [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Let's assign some values. Java provides [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing) for automatically converting `int` values into `Integer` objects.

```
    integers[ 2 ] = 42 ;                      // Auto-boxing.
    integers[ 5 ] = Integer.valueOf( 99 ) ;   // Unnecessary, because of auto-boxing.
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( integers ) ) ;
```

When run, we see two slots are used while ten remain unused (`null`).

> [null, null, 42, null, null, 99, null, null, null, null, null, null]

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/QccXf7).

You said:

> I want to see if `array[5]` holds a value or is empty.

Test for `null`.

```
boolean slotAtIndex5HoldsObjectRef = ( null != integers[ 5 ] ) ;  // Parens are not necessary, but improve readability.
```

> true

More elegant to use the [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) utility class.

```
boolean slot5Filled = Objects.nonNull( integers[ 5 ] ) ;
```

> true

Specify [a default value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)) if none assigned.

```
    Integer x = Objects.requireNonNullElse( integers[ 5 ] , Integer.valueOf( 101 ) ) ;
    Integer y = Objects.requireNonNullElse( integers[ 7 ] , Integer.valueOf( 101 ) ) ;
```

> x: 99
>
> y: 101

Answer (score -1):

Create a constant to define the empty value, eg:

```
private static final int EMPTY = -1;
```

then create the array like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[size];
Arrays.fill(myArray, EMPTY);
```

then to check if an element is 'empty', do this:

```
if (myArray[i] == EMPTY)
{
   //element i is empty
}
```

Comment: It's tough to come up with a constant that you can guarantee will never be a valid value that could legitimately be put in the array. 

If you really have to know whether anything has been added, probably better to use an array of Integers and check for null.

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point, but I find in practice there is usually a range of valid integers that will be added to the array, so for example, a negative integer, or Integer.MAX/MIN_VALUE, can be used as EMPTY.